# Text view's XCUIElement's value is nil in iOS 12 simulator

Tags: swift, xcuitest

I have a text view whose text value is different than the empty string, which I retrieve this way:

```
let textViews = self.app.textViews.matching(identifier: "CommentTextView")
XCTAssertEqual(textViews.count, 1)

commentTextView = textViews.element(boundBy: 0)
XCTAssert(commentTextView.exists)

guard let text = commentTextView.value as? String else {
    XCTFail()
    return
}
```

Now this test doesn't fail on the iOS 13 simulator, and I am able to verify that the string value is correct. But on the iOS 12 simulator, the value is nil and the test fails. And it's failing also on the iOS 11 simulator. Any idea why this is failing only for iOS 12 or lower? is there any other way of retrieving the text view's value?

Update: I tried also on a real device with iOS 12, and the tests don't fail. At the moment it looks weird to me that the tests are failing only on the simulator, and I suspect that it might be a bug in the API.

Comment: I'm encountering the same thing.  Have you found a solution to this yet or confirmed that it's a bug in the the API?

Answer (score 0):

Several things could be wrong here. Are you transitioning from a new screen? If so, you should wait for existence. When looking for elements in my test I write something similar to the following:

```
// Set globally. You can use one for api calls and the other for transition timeouts.
let defaultTimeout = 70.0
let transitionTimeout = 5.0

let commentTextView = self.app.textViews["CommentTextView"].firstMatch
let commentTextViewFound = commentTextView.waitForExistence(timeout: self.transitionTimeout)
XCTAssert(commentTextViewFound, "CommentTextView was not found.")


// Already transitioned at this point. No need to wait for existence again.

let buttonExample = self.app.buttons["ButtonExample"].firstMatch
XCTAssert(buttonExample.exists, "ButtonExample was not found.")

buttonExample.tap()
```

Comment: I already have an assertion: "XCTAssert(commentTextView.exists)", which doesn't fail. So it doesn't make any difference if I wait for its existence or not.

Answer (score 0):

Suffer the same issue and workaround as self.app.textViews.firstMatch or self.app.textViews.element(boundBy: 0) works for me, within iOS 12.4.